# Messenger application approved, non developers unable to interact with messenger application

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have A application for Facebook messenger, I submitted my application for review facebook approved the submission, but I'm still unable to interact with my application from a non developer account. I tried the following steps;

- Research documentation, validate if all required permissions are submitted for review.
- Reconnecting facebook app to messenger.
- Resubscribe application to events.
- Recreate facebook page token.

[image: Granted permissions]

Does someone have an idea what could be wrong? I'm pretty clueless at this point.

Comment: Is your app in live mode?

Comment: @04FS Yes it is.

Comment: So what exactly is failing, what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: @04FS I'm expecting to receive a request on my webhook service when a user sends a message to a subscribed page, when the user isn't a administrator, developer or tester Facebook does not make any request to my webhook service.

Comment: But it works for users with a role in the app? That would be the classic dev mode vs live mode scenario, maybe try switching the app to dev and then live again and see if that changes anything? If it doesn’t, and you are sure everything is set up correctly, maybe file a bug report and ask them to check into what is going on.

Comment: @04FS Just created a bug report at facebook. Thanks!